# Pointless use of PrintStream?

Tags: java

I'm looking at a class which takes an `OutputStream` object via its constructor and the uses it to create a `PrintStream` object as follows:

```
this.pout = new PrintStream(out);
```

Then this class uses the `pout` object in the following manner in a number of places in the class implementation:

```
String string;
...
pout.print(string);
pout.flush();
```

Am I correct in saying that the use of PrintStream here is pointless and that this would have done the same job:

```
this.out = out
...
out.print(string);
out.flush();
```

where out is of type `OutputStream`.

Also, I am using this class to write out a command on an a ssh2 connection. I then use a class implementing `InputStream` to read back the response. Is there any behind the scenes syncing between `OutputStream` and `InputStream` or should I always call flush before polling for a reply?

Comment: If you had tried it you would have found the answer for yourself in about 30 seconds.

Comment: @EJP Not true, I missed the fact that OutputStream worked on bytes only when looking at the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second snippet is invalid. [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) does not have a `print()` method.

> Is there any behind the scenes syncing between `OutputStream` and `InputStream` or should I always call flush before polling for a reply?

This depends on the mechanics of the actual stream classes that you're using. If in doubt, use `flush()`.

Comment: I can remove the flushes if I create the PrintStream object with its autoFlush argument set to true.

Comment: `PrintStream` also handles being passed `null` argument to the `print` method by printing "null".

Comment: Emil H Only String objects are being passed to the print method, in the code I'm looking at.

Answer (score 1):

print() calls write() but hides any IOException which might occur.  This is usually more dangerous than useful unless you are writing to device which should never fail or will only fail if its in the users control e.g. System.out and System.err are PrintStream and the caller of the program may close these when the program is run.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the obvious lack of `print...()` methods in `OutputStream`, PrintStream also suppresses `IOException` and sets an error flag instead.